# Where can I purchase a superuser t-shirt?

Tags: support, super-contest, t-shirt

Saw that there were some contests a while ago and I would love to be able to purchase my own shirt as I was not a member of the community when the contests took place.

Does anybody know where I can buy one?

Comment: I wish they made a merchandising shop with T-shirts that say: SuperUser's fixed my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get a hold of one as far as I am aware is through competitions. On occasion the team will also send T-Shirts to users on Page 1 of the users list. Also keep your eye on the [blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com), Jeff on occasion will send T-Shirts to users who give good comments.

There will be more contests in future. Continue being a positive and noticeable member and a T-Shirt will eventually find it's way to you.

The T-Shirts aren't available for purchase. It makes them more exclusive that way.

Comment: did this change recently? I remember a shop page where you can purchase, but I can't find any reference to the page now and the one link I did have appears to be dead.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. There was a link to a site that we bought them from to see samples on Meta when the idea first came up, but AFAIK you could never buy them.